# Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'int'

Tags: c#, datetime, casting

How to solve this issue

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
DateTime s = (DateTime)dobcalender.SelectedDate;


int years = now.Year - s.Year;
if (now.Month < s.Month || (now.Month == s.Month && now.Day < s.Day))
    --years;
tb_age.Text = years.ToString();


if (_data.Age >= 60)
{
    _data.Citizen = "Senior";
}
else
{
    _data.Citizen = "Junior";
}
```

Now the problem is that i have declared _data.Age is as int32.

i have to calculate the age from date of birth and also check whether  the person is senior citizen or junior
Both values are calculated from the age.

Comment: Are you sure this is a C program?

Comment: I'm sure Age is not declared as Int32, but as DateTime

Comment: Are you sure you declared `_data.Age` as `int32`?  The only line with `>=` in it in your code is `if(_data.Age >= 60)` and the error reports comparing `DateTime` with `int`

Comment: sorry thank u man it is declared as date time

Comment: @NidheeshNNamboodhiri well there's your problem. Age seems like it should be an integer, not a DateTime.

Comment: so u mean i have to change datetime to int  isn't it?

Comment: CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            _data.Date = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault();
            _data.BranchName = tb_branchname.Text;
            _data.City = tb_city.Text;
            _data.Country = ddl_country.SelectedValue;
            _data.DateOfBirth = tb_dob.Text;
            _data.Age = tb_age.Text;
            _data.DateOfIssue = tb3.Text;
            _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_data.Age is declared as a `DateTime` variable.  Change this to an `int` to resolve this error.